# Maui Handler Approach (List)

Tags: xamarin.forms, handler, maui

I was wondering if there was a list of what views/elements get linked with what handlers.

i.e. what handler should I use for a viewCell
I know there are some obvious ones i.e. button or entry

Comment: You are looking for this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-7.0#handler-based-views

Comment: That is exactly it! :)

Comment: @FreakyAli would you know why     public CustomViewCellHandler() : base(CustomViewCellMapper)
doesn't work?

Comment: Freaky, that comment is worth making an answer!

Comment: Yes, it could be an answer which could help people with same questions.

Comment: Ok i will add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ever want to know which Maui Control uses which Handlers/Renderers the easiest way is to check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-7.0#handler-based-views

It gives you all the details you need from which interface to use to the property mapper it should use.